# Angular 2 RC4 RxJS Crash

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a piece of code that worked perfectly until the latest Angular 2 update. Among other things, it uses Http requests & Observables.

I updated to RC4, import all RxJS operators (to make sure it works) and I get Error: SecurityError: DOM Exception 18

Any idea why and how I can fix this?

Simplified code snippet:

```
logIn(email: string, pass: string): Observable<boolean> {
  return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
    let body = {
      email: email,
      pass: pass
    };

    this.http.post(this.origin + "/auth/logIn", JSON.stringify(body), this.requestArguments())
      .subscribe((res: Response) => {
        observer.next(res.json()["isLoggedIn"]);
        observer.complete();
      })
  })
}
```

Where

```
this.origin = window.location.origin + "/api"
```

Weirdly:

Safari throws the exception

Chrome doesn't, but the page seems to get stuck

Firefox works properly.

And all of this is sporadic.. sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: DOMS Exception 18 is mostly because you're not using it from localhost server. Put it on localhost instead of directly opening.

Comment: It is on localhost, served through node

Comment: Take a look at this post - http://tosbourn.com/a-fix-for-window-location-origin-in-internet-explorer/

Comment: Is your Safari browser set to accept cookies?

Comment: can you post your package.json here ?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail? with your package.json ?

Comment: Please post stack trace

Comment: Could you please try with angular window ( $window ) instead direct window object ( this.origin = $window.location.origin + "/api" )

Answer (score 1):

All angular RC versions depends on the same rxjs 5.0.0 beta 6, so I think you are looking at the wrong direction. your code though smells weired to me. http call inside a create function? your http response holds an observable, why do you try to create your own observable? if you need to map your object use map